# Sorting bibliography in alphabetical order without using bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, alphabet

Is there a way to sort the bibliography in alphabetical order without using bibtex, I am making a one-time project so dont really want to have to use bibtex. I tried using \bibliographystyle{plain} but that didnt work.

Comment: Simply write the entries in the bibliography environment in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Bibtex is not *that* hard to use. It gives you a structured format for collecting data on citations, and even many journals and preprint collections offer you ready-made (almost -- they often require some tweaking) entries. And you can reuse the data collected in later endeavours.